# Mercurial: How to add a file from an ignored folder?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, hgignore

I have added a folder to the file `.hgignore` and hence the files in it (and inside it subdirectories) are ignored. However, I just added a file to one of the subdirectories of the ignored folder. How do I add that file to list of tracked files?

I guess this is one of the downsides of using a GUI for version control. I am using `SourceTree` and have little direct exposure to `Hg` commands (although I have enabled the option to show the commands when they are executed and do observe what `Hg` is doing in the background). I tried googling the question but couldn't find any relevant result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can individually track an ignored file simply by adding it explicitly. From the `.hgignore` man page:

> An untracked file X can be explicitly added with hg add X, even if X would be excluded by a pattern in .hgignore.

Your express intent to add this file is presumed to override your preferences in `.hgignore`.

The purpose of `.hgignore` is primarily to not have ignored files included when you add a directory in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your repository's "`.hgignore`" file and specify that you want the directory tree to be ignored except this file. For example if you have the following structure:

```
└── a
    ├── b.txt
    └── c.txt
```

and you would like to ignore everything but *not* "`c.txt`", then depending on the `.hgignore` file contents you can have:

Without any `.hgignore` file:

```
$ hg status
? a/b.txt
? a/c.txt
```

With a line to ignore everything under "`a`":

```
$ cat .hgignore 
syntax: regexp
^a/
$ hg status
? .hgignore
```

And with an other line to ignore everything under "`a`" but *not* the "`c.txt`" file:

```
$ cat .hgignore 
syntax: regexp
^a/(?!c.txt).*
$ hg status
? .hgignore
? a/c.txt
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: This is well meaning, but totally overkill.  As Reimer points out adding a file overrides its ignored status.  Using a zero-with-negative-lookahead pattern in a .hgignore is never necessary and seldom a good idea.